# Extracting a specific value from an ANOVA test in R

Tags: r

I have performed an ANOVA test for a data with calcium content of materials using the code anova(calcium.aov) and obtained the following:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: calcium
              Df   Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
factor(batch)  4 0.096976 0.024244  5.5352 0.003626 **
Residuals     20 0.087600 0.004380
```

My aim is to extract the MSE (=0.004380) only, so I entered the code

```
anova(calcium.aov)[3][2]
```

But I keep on getting the error message

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(anova(calcium.aov)[3], 2) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the contents of `anova`, you'll have to use `$`; `anova()$****`. Start by defining it as a variable, `anova_var <- anova(calcium.aov)`, and then `anova_var$` - then all you options will be there.

More elaborately,

```
# Fit by LM
fit <- lm(
    mpg ~ cyl,
    data = mtcars
)

# Save Anova as variable
anova_fit <- anova(fit)

# Get MSE
anova_fit$`Mean Sq`[2]

# Alternatively

anova(fit)$`Mean Sq`[2]
```

Alternatively, you can use,

```
# As Anova has class data.frame
anova_fit["Mean Sq"][2,]
```

In any case you'll get what you want, and I guess it comes down to preference really.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
anova(calcium.aov)["Residuals", "Mean Sq"]
```